# SAS EG 7.15 ERROR: CLI error trying to establish connection: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_ENV failed

Tags: sas, odbc

I have SAS EG version: 7.15 HF8  (64-bit)

When I tried to run the code like this
`libname xxx odbc datasrc=xxx schema=xxx user=&xxx password=&xxx;`

I received the error messgae:

**ERROR: CLI error trying to establish connection: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_ENV failed**

**ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.**

I tried to google the solution, https://support.sas.com/kb/44/284.html suggests that the reason might be 
'The wrong SAS PC Files Server has been installed'.

I checked my office version, which is 32 bit. And I don't have SAS PC Files Server installed.
The SAS PC Files Server through the link above seems to be only available for SAS 9.4 and 9.3.and not compatible with earlier version of SAS ...

I also looked into ODBC related trouble shooting but had no luck.
Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What version of SAS are you using?

Comment: @StuSztukowski  SAS Enterprise Guide 7.15

Comment: That is the IDE you are using. What version of SAS are you connected to? For example, 9.4M6, 9.3, etc.